# Nginx 301 redirect catch all

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

Recently i discovered that some site is linking many no existing url's (missing the .html) to my domain. 
I will try to lower the crawl errors by pointing all this 404 wrong urls to the correct ones.

But i am having trouble making the 301 redirect in nginx

I want to redirect domain.com/mp3/search to domain.com/mp3/search.html

My current config is :

```
       location / {
rewrite ^/mp3/([^/]*).html(/?)+$ /index.php?mp3=$1;

#rewrite ^/mp3/([^/]*).html(/?)+$ /index.php?mp3=$1;
#rewrite ^/mp3/([^/]*)$ /$1.html;

}
```

I have tried with

```
#rewrite ^/mp3/([^/]*).html(/?)+$ /index.php?mp3=$1;
```

it just creates a domain.com/mp3/search page

```
 #rewrite ^/mp3/([^/]*)$ /$1.html;
```

returns 404

more examples :

```
mp3/Rank_1_&_Dennis_Sheperd  to become  mp3/Rank_1_&_Dennis_Sheperd.html
mp3/Flashlight_ to become mp3/Flashlight_.html
mp3/Let_her_go_ to become mp3/Let_her_go_.html
mp3/Audien_-_Iris to become mp3/Audien_-_Iris.html
```

all with 301 redirect

Comment: I hope you know that configuration lines starting with the `#` character are considered as comments and aren't executed by nginx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the rewrite rule you're looking for is:

```
rewrite ^/mp3/([^/]*)(?!.html)$ /mp3/$1.html permanent;
```

Comment: with that i get a 200 status on /mp3/search its the same page as /mp3/search.html , but witouth the .html at the ending . I think i would need to do that for all the pages with /mp3/ that dont have ".html" at the ending

Comment: I said that all redirects should be done for all the urls that dont contain .html at the ending , because with that redirect, on normal pages : ex /mp3/keyword.html , in the php i get the keywords from the url and instead of keyword i have "keyword.html" in the script.

Comment: The reason you're seeing a 200 status on /mp3/search instead of seeing /mp3/search.html is because you're applying a rewrite rule. You need to add the `permanent` keyword at the end of the line to get the 301 redirect. (changed answer accordingly)

Comment: I also changed the rule so that the rule doesn't apply to URLs having `.html` at the end

Comment: thanks for the new code, it seems to do the 301 redirect but something strange is happening mp3/search gets redirected to http://domain/mp3/search.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html

Comment: also a regular .html link , ex : domian/mp3/search.html gets also redirected to the multiple .html.html.html ex: http://domian.com/mp3/abba.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html

Comment: aah , i put the rewrite at the bottom of the location / and now it works . thanks very much !